# How can I compare numbers in an object against text in the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop, random

I have a function that picks a random number from 1 - 6 and then appends it to the DOM. I am trying to compare that number to numbers that are currently in a div in the DOM. So I stored those numbers in a var called cards. When I console.log() the var it returns an array. I converted that array to a string and then I retrieved the text. What is the best way to go about comparing the numbers? Should I do a for loop and if any of those numbers match one of the random numbers drawn take some action? Can some one show me an example of doing this? My code is below.

```
 $(function(){
   function dice1(){
       var randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
       $('#instructions').text(randomNumber);
       return randomNumber;
   }
    function dice2(){
        var randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        $('#instructions2').text(randomNumber);
        return randomNumber;

    }
    $('#dice1').click(function() {
        dice1();
        var cards = $('#cards div');
        var single = cards.toString();

        console.log(cards.text());
        if ($('#instructions').text() == cards.text()) {
            console.log('match');
        }

    });

    $('#dice2').click(function(){
        dice2();
    });


 });
  <section id="container">
    <div id="cards">
        <div id="1">1</div>
        <div id="2">2</div>
        <div id="3">3</div>
        <div id="4">4</div>
        <div id="5">5</div>
        <div id="6">6</div>
        <div id="7">7</div>
        <div id="8">8</div>
        <div id="9">9</div>
    </div>

    <section>
        <button id="dice1">Roll dice1</button>
        <button id="dice2">Roll dice2</button>
        <div id="instructions"></div>
        <div id="instructions2"></div>
    </section>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the cards directly in an array like this:

```
var cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Then do the comparison like this:

```
var number = parseInt($("#instructions").text());

if(cards.indexOf(number) >= 0)
    console.log("Number found");
else
    console.log("Number not found");
```

If you really want to do it your way, you can do this:

```
$(".cards div").each(function(){
    var number = parseInt($("#instructions").text());
    var card = parseInt($(this).text());
    if(card == number)
            console.log("Number found");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could indeed do it with a for loop:

```
$('#dice1').click(function() {
    var random_number = dice1();
    var cards = $('#cards div');

    for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++ ) {
       if($(this).html() == random_number) {
           alert('Do something!');
       }
    }

    console.log(cards.text());
    if ($('#instructions').text() == cards.text()) {
        console.log('match');
    }

});
```

But you could also directly match to the ID you've set:

```
$('#dice1').click(function() {
    var random_number = dice1();
    var card = $('#cards div[id='+random_number+']');
    if(card.length > 0) {
        alert('Do something!');
    }
});
```

Remember though, that the ID attribute can not start with a number, so I would create my own attribute here:

```
<div id="cards">
    <div data-number="1">1</div>
    <div data-number="2">2</div>
    <div data-number="3">3</div>
    <div data-number="4">4</div>
    <div data-number="5">5</div>
    <div data-number="6">6</div>
    <div data-number="7">7</div>
    <div data-number="8">8</div>
    <div data-number="9">9</div>
</div>
```

And then use jQuery like so:

```
$('#dice1').click(function() {
    var random_number = dice1();
    var card = $('#cards div[data-number='+random_number+']');
    if(card.length > 0) {
        alert('Do something!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

New JS:

```
 $(function () {
     function dice1() {
         var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
         $('#instructions').text(randomNumber);
         return randomNumber;
     }

     function dice2() {
         var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
         $('#instructions2').text(randomNumber);
         return randomNumber;

     }
     $('#dice1').click(function () {
         var num1 = dice1();

         $('#cards div').each(function (index,item) {
             if ($(item).text() == num1) {
                 $(item).css("color", "red");
             }
         });


         $('#dice2').click(function () {
             dice2();
         });


     });
 });
```

[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdgkhzfn/)

Answer (score 0):

I just learned a way of doing it that solves it dynamically and personally I think it's easier to follow.

```
 <div data-hook="cards" id="cards">
        <div data-value="1" id="1">1</div>
        <div data-value="2" id="2">2</div>
        <div data-value="3" id="3">3</div>
        <div data-value="4" id="4">4</div>
        <div data-value="5" id="5">5</div>
        <div data-value="6" id="6">6</div>
        <div data-value="7" id="7">7</div>
        <div data-value="8" id="8">8</div>
        <div data-value="9" id="9">9</div>
    </div>

 $(function(){
   function dice1(){
       var randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
       $('#instructions').text(randomNumber);
       return randomNumber;
   }

    $('#dice1').click(function() {
        dice1();

        $('[data-hook=cards] [data-value]').find('#instructions'); //'data-hook=cards] [data-value]' selects the element by attr'
        var rolledNum = $('#instructions').text(),
                selector = '[data-value=' + rolledNum + ']',
                $card = $('[data-hook=cards]').find(selector);
        //Instead of using an $.each or for loop to compare two numbers I am taking the random number and finding it on the div and then modifying the div.
        console.log($card);
        $card.css({'opacity':.2});

    });        
 });
```